# mysql select to insert two values from one specific row and plus two values (paired) from some random row

Tags: mysql

This question [Mysql Select some random rows and plus one specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863482/mysql-select-some-random-rows-and-plus-one-specific-row) comes very close to what I want, except that I don't know how to apply ORDER BY to my situation.

When someone accepts an invitation to join my website, I want to add that invitee to a 'friends' list connected to their inviter, but I also want to add 1 or 2 random invitees to get them started growing a network. Here's what is working to add the invitee:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend) VALUES (SELECT users.user as user1, invited.user as user2 FROM users INNER JOIN invited ON users.email=invited.invitee
```

I select the user name of the person who invited plus the person who was invited and then joined and insert this into the friends table. So far so good for the inviter, but how do I add random friends? Is there a way to tack onto this statement to also add 1 or 2 random user names from the users table?

I really want to insert the following (where user1 is always the same person):

(user1, friend discovered by inner join)
(user1, rand user)
(user1, another rand user)

Here's what I'd like to do but isn't working:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend) VALUES (SELECT users.user as user1, invited.user as user2 FROM users INNER JOIN invited ON users.email=invited.invitee), (user1, SELECT user FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),  (user1, SELECT user FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

But this just gets me the following not very helpful error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT users.user as user1, invited.user as user2 FROM users INNER JOIN invited ' at line 1
```

Is there another way to do this with a single function call? Or if not, what would be the most efficient way to do this with prepared statements?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the structure of the `users` and `invited` tables;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were pretty close.

In this case rather than getting caught up in the joins (except for the first one you needed) and the subqueries you can use simple [variable assignment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) and a `UNION` clause. The only other thing missing that was causing an issue was that you need to use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` syntax vs. `INSERT INTO...VALUES` syntax ([Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20667/mysql-insert-into-select-union)).

```
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend) 
SELECT @user1:=users.user as user1, invited.user as user2 
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN invited 
    ON users.email=invited.invitee
    WHERE invited.invitee = 'baz@bar.com'
UNION ALL
(SELECT @user1 as user1, user 
FROM users 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: Note the above has potential to create duplicates -- would be good to wrap the SELECT with a SELECT DISTINCT to make sure nothing is inserted twice.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! And I learned a lot here that I wasn't aware of as a sql newbie.

Comment: @Beeb - please accept the answer if it works for ya. I can't recommend enough to folks new to MySQL to check out the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html. Lots of examples, and mysql has some weird gotchas vs. other languages.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that it will do the insert for every SELECT @ user1:=users.user from the original SELECT...INNER JOIN...statement? Right now the above is working for an individual user, but I actually want to insert 2 random friends for any row that has been SELECTED/INSERTED from the INNER JOIN query.

Comment: @Beeb - can you update a simple example to show what table would look like after i.e. user|friend,[1,2],[1,5], etc?